# Iterating through a set of key/value pair to set values

Tags: javascript, iteration

What initially appeared to be a no-brainer got me scratching my head and wondering why I can't seem to iterate through a simple list of value/key pairs to reset all values to zero. My code (javascript) looks as follows:

```
var theme = {
    facilityNRCount: 5,
    facilityMOCount: 2,
    facilitySMCount: 8,
    ....
    physicalSecCount: 9,
    energyWaterCount: 1,
    otherSustCount: 10
};

$.each(theme, function(k, v) {
    v = 0;
});
```

And apparently I'm missing something, which isn't so obvious to me. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Km5BA/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.each` function doesn't use references.  The `v` is just the value, not a reference to it.

Try this:

```
for(var k in theme){
    if(theme.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        theme[k] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$.each(theme, function(k) { theme[k] = 0; })` should've worked as well

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, it would.  This was just the first thing that I thought of :-)